# What are uses of the byte after BRK instruction on 6502?

Tags: 6502, interrupt

The `BRK` instruction on the MOS 6502 seems to be one of the more
ill-documented features of the processor. The [1976 preliminary data
sheet from MOS](http://archive.6502.org/datasheets/mos_6500_mpu_preliminary_may_1976.pdf) indicates that it's a 1-byte instruction using
the "implied" addressing mode (i.e., it has no operands), as does the
the [1980 CSG data sheet](http://archive.6502.org/datasheets/mos_6500_mpu_mar_1980.pdf).¹ (Edit: the [MCS6500 Microcomputer
Family Programminng Manual](https://archive.org/details/6500-50a_mcs6500pgmmanjan76) does describe the details and
intention of the `BRK` instruction in §9.11  pp. 144-146.)

However, unlike an IRQ interrupting any other 1-byte instruction, the
program counter pushed on to the stack when a `BRK` is executed does
not point to the byte immediately after the opcode but instead to the
*second* byte after the opcode. (This is mentioned nowhere in those
two data sheets.²)

Given the lack of documentation about this, I'm guessing that this was
unintentional³ (though evidence otherwise is welcome!), because it
wastes the byte after the `BRK` if the interrupt handler does an `RTI`
to the address pushed by the `BRK` after handling it. (If there was no
`RTI`, the byte need not be wasted: control would never flow past the
`BRK` and so another routine could have an entry point immediately
after it. This was the case on, e.g., the Apple II, where a BRK would
stop whatever program was executing and enter the monitor.⁴)

I'm looking for examples in "real-world" code (as opposed to
demonstration or example code) of how this "spare byte" was used in
systems with IRQ routines that did an `RTI` to return to the address
pushed by the `BRK` instruction.⁵ This could be use by the IRQ routine
itself (as a parameter, or similar, e.g. as Woz sugested in his
[November 1977 *BYTE* article on Sweet 16](http://amigan.1emu.net/kolsen/programming/sweet16.html)) or something else.

Ideally the examples would be from widely distributed software for
6502-based general purpose computers. Again, I'm not too interested in
demo code that shows how it *could* be used in a theoretical
real-world program. But if you feel you have an example that has
something useful to offer beyond the limited technical details of
*how* to implement this, feel free post an answer about it.

---

¹<sub>Both have a note "See Fig. 1" beside the instruction in the
instruction set/opcde table, but none of the figures in either
document are numbered, and none seem to be relevant. I welcome
clarification of this.</sub>

²<sub>The ignored byte after the `BRK` is kind of implied by the cycle
breakdown of the `BRK` instruction on page A-11 of the 1976 [MCS6500
Microcomputer Family Hardware Manual](http://archive.6502.org/books/mcs6500_family_hardware_manual.pdf), where after the T0
cycle reads the opcode the subsequent T1 cycle puts on the address bus
"PC + 1 (PC on hardware interrupt)" before pushing the PC on to the
stack in T2 and T3. But documenting it as a one-byte instruction or
opcode with no operands, despite the byte after it being skipped,
persists even today in the 2018 [WDC W65C02S data sheet](http://archive.6502.org/datasheets/wdc_w65c02s_oct_8_2018.pdf).


     [This post on forum.6502.org](http://forum.6502.org/viewtopic.php?t=1917#p15845) does say, "WDC
describes BRK as '...a 2 byte instruction. The NMOS and CMOS devices
simply skips [sic] the second byte (i.e. doesn’t care about the second
byte) by incrementing the program counter twice.'" However, it doesn't
give a source for that quote.</sub>

³<sub>By "unintentional" I mean that having that unused byte after the
`BRK` instruction was not a design goal. In this context, "we've got
an unused byte there but it isn't a problem and that lets us save
transistors (or whatever) elsewhere" does not count as
"intentional."</sub>

⁴<sub>See the `IRQ` routine at `$FA86` in the BIOS listing on page 81
(PDF page 84) of the [Apple II Reference Manual](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_appleapple_10059029/page/n83).</sub>

⁵<sub>An IRQ routine could use bit 4 of the program status register
value pushed on to the stack to determine it had been invoked by a
`BRK` and then use the PC pushed on to the stack to find the spare
byte. [Wilson Mines](http://wilsonminesco.com/6502interrupts/#2.2) gives details on how to do this.</sub>

Comment: I'd also say it is unintentional, and probably a consequence of the "pipelining" done inside the 6502. One could check the "how" on visual6502.org. I've never seen an example where the byte after the BRK is used, though that doesn't mean there aren't any ... Though I know examples where bytes after a JSR have been used (e.g. in the Apple II Sweet Sixteen interpreter).

Comment: "Intentional" is a fuzzy thing. If it got that way as a result of transistor count, and someone at MOS noticed it and said "hey, that could actually be useful as a way to get information to the BRK handler, make sure not to change it", is that intentional or not? Several older architectures, before the "stack" concept was well-developed, would use caller-PC-relative data like that, so it's not an unheard-of idea.

Comment: @hobbs You could still use that technique to get information to the `BRK` handler if the return address were the one right after `BRK`, rather than the one after, just as is done with `JSR`. And that seems to me simpler because you don't have to remember to skip a byte before starting your next instruction (e.g., by always putting a `NOP` after `BRK`) if you're using a handler that _doesn't_ take parameter data after the instruction.

Comment: I'm also keeping away from intentional/unintentional but I'll vote for: likely easier. All single-byte 6502 instructions do a redundant fetch of the byte after them both for the usual 6502 marking-time reasons and to unify the one-byte and two-byte instruction execution patterns, so I'll guess that BRK just lets slide an internal modification to the PC that the other one-byte instructions undo.

Comment: @Tommy: The 6502 determines what address will be accessed on any given cycle before it has received the byte of data from the previous cycle.  An instruction like INX requires an internal bus cycle to read the old value from the X register and an internal cycle to write the new value; the read takes place during the dummy operand fetch and the write-back during the next opcode fetch.  NOP is just about the only instruction that could realistically execute as one-byte-one-cycle.

Comment: `BRK` is like `INT` instruction of x86. The following byte is number of software interrupt (or can be used for this purpose).

Comment: @i486 Actually it seems to me closer to the x86 `INT3` instruction (0xCC), which is a single-byte instruction that uses a fixed vector (as `BRK` does), rather than the `INT nn` instruction (0xCD _nn_) which routes to one of 256 different vectors, which the 6502 cannot do. Note that you can replace any instruction byte with an `INT3` or `BRK`, but you cannot do so with `INT`; you _must_ replace the byte after the instruction with your vector number as well.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson You have to implement programatically the extraction of following byte and make indirect jump with vector table. I have made it on Apple II but it costs many cycles.

Comment: @i486 Right. I mentioned this in footnote 5, with a link to the details. This could also be implemented with `JSR`.

Answer (score 30):

On the BBC Micro, the byte after the BRK instruction held the error number, followed by the error message string terminated with 0x0D. CALLing the address of the BRK instruction would cause an error to be raised.

Update with example, as a runnable BBC BASIC program:

```
10 DIM b% 32
20 ?b%=0: REM BRK
30 ?(b%+1)=42: REM Error number 42
40 $(b%+2)="StackExchange"
50 CALL b%
>RUN

StackExchange at line 50
>PRINT ERR
        42
>_
```

Comment: Can you describe in a little more detail how this worked? For example, was code after the `BRK` and its following argument ever executed, or did that always just terminate the program right there?

Comment: I've given an example of how it would be invoked, as a BASIC program (though, more likely it would be a machine code routine that would do this).  As for terminating the program, if ?(b%+1) isn't zero the error is trappable with ON ERROR, with the error number in ERR, the line number in ERL and the text of the error in REPORT$.

Comment: So just to confirm, in this code, if there were another line, `60 PRINT "Continuing..."`, that would not be executed before you ended up back at the BASIC prompt?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: So this answer doesn't actually answer my real question, though it was very helpful in helping my clarify what I was actually trying ask. (So thanks!) I've rewritten my question to make it clear that I'm looking for examples that do an RTI to the address pushed by the `BRK`.

Comment: I expect that would be in the BBC Micro MOS routines that raise the actual error condition in my example, so BASIC gets control back.

Comment: Do you really think it's doing an RTI, and not just jumping into another part of BASIC? If it did the RTI, then there'd have to be some other way of informing BASIC to stop running the program at that point, rather than carrying on.

Comment: Due to the modular nature of the BBC Micro, it needs a language-independent nature of handling error messages - that same mechanism of throwing an error is used in, for example, the DFS ROM to report errors such as "Disc fault", then return control to the running language (or in the case of the BBC Master which has an OS prompt), the Operating System CLI.

Comment: Very interesting! I'd certainly be interested in the details of how this actually happens.

Comment: For fun: https://bbc.godbolt.org/?loadBasic=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mattgodbolt/9b5932abf238c91cbf36083813e7ce16/raw/1dc3d7c7126dbbc7a82d6039cb2c15495f979eb5/brk.bas&autorun will demo this from a gist (https://gist.github.com/mattgodbolt/9b5932abf238c91cbf36083813e7ce16 )

Comment: This is certainly a common technique for reporting errors: issue a trapping instruction with an error code in the instruction stream.  I've used that on PDP-11 (IOT) and VAX (BUGW, BUGL).  True, in these cases one needs to 'manually' advance the return PC across the error code.

Answer (score 25):

> The BRK instruction on the MOS 6502 seems to be one of the more ill-documented features of the processor. [...]
>   Given the lack of documentation about this

It is documented quite well and in depth in the corresponding *MCS 6500 Microcomputer Family Programming Manual* of January 1976 (and all follow ups). Check page 144 and after for description, reasoning and examples.

> (This is mentioned nowhere in those two data sheets.)

Data sheets aren't meant as full documentation, but rather giving an overview.

> However, unlike an IRQ interrupting any other 1-byte instruction,

This might be a first misunderstanding. `BRK` isn't a 1-byte instruction interrupted by `IRQ`, but rather an instruction working like `IRQ`. The difference is in cause and effect - here the way the instruction works. With an external interrupt it gets handled *before* the PC is advanced on the next instruction (technically by inserting a `BRK`). With a BRK the instruction gets fetched and processed (over two cycles) before the PC is pushed.

Still this doesn't make it a two byte instruction, it stays a one byte instruction with the workings of advancing PC by two before pushing.

> I'm guessing that this was unintentional (though evidence otherwise is welcome!),

I'd say it was quite intentional. With the 6500 being designed as an extremely low cost CPU, it was what could be achieved with a bare minimum in additional circuitry. So instead of setting up a separate vector the IRQ vector was used - in fact, BRK processing is even used to make IRQ/NMI/RES happen.

The increment by two is part of this too, as that's the default behaviour of 6502 instructions, as all take two cycles at least. Single byte instructions need to explicitly disable the increment during the second cycle. Since BRK isn't a normal instruction, intended to be executed in a regular sequence and situation, adding that correction wouldn't make any difference.

BRK was never intended to be more than a debugging aid. A use that never comes up in regular use, thus its rather cumbersome detection and the need to readjust PC as well did not do much harm. In fact, being a debugging tool, readjusting the PC to the original instruction address and replacing the instruction overwritten (*1) had to be done anyway.

It's all about offering an in-place debugging-aid with the least effort possible.

Similar the use of x'00' as opcode as any (back then) (E)PROM can always be patched to contain all zero in a location, enabling debugging of PROM code. Similar is forcing the data bus to zero, to detect a special case during problem analysis,  an easy task, not requiring a lot of hardware.

All of this has to be seen interlinked.

> but it does allow you to do something interesting, which is to use the byte after the BRK as a parameter to the IRQ routine.

Yes, that has been done many times. After all, and at first sight, it seems like a really nifty ***S**uper**V**isor **C**all* type of instruction. Looking closely it does involve quite some address juggling. So much so that more performance-aware developers usually preferred to use `JSR` calls instead, as their return address can be used directly with less stack mangling as well (*2).

> I'm not terribly interested in examples from embedded systems

Sure, valid point - still, to understand why things have been made the way they are, it's always a good idea to keep in mind that the 6502 wasn't developed with a general purpose computer in mind, but embedded use. The whole point was to make a very cheap CPU and support it with (for that time) quite complex and versatile I/O companion chips integrating several previous separate components into one (e.g. 653x type).

---

*1 - Or emulating it and advancing the PC to after the whole instruction

*2 - See the [ProDOS MLI](http://www.easy68k.com/paulrsm/6502/PDOS8TRM.HTM#4) as main example, but IIRC Woz used it already in 1977 to call [Sweet-16](http://amigan.1emu.net/kolsen/programming/sweet16.html) sequences.

Comment: "BRK isn't a 1-byte instruction interrupted by IRQ, but rather an instruction working like IRQ." No misunderstanding here; this is exactly what I meant. That's why I said "an IRQ interrupting any _other_ 1-byte instruction." Thanks for your explanation of the implementation of `BRK`; I had suspected it was something like this that led to the "spare byte."

Comment: I've also added footnote ³ to clarify what I mean by "unintentional." In this context, that extra byte appears, from your description, indeed to have been unintentional.

Comment: Regarding Sweet 16, Woz used `JSR` in the Apple II, presumably because `BRK` was [already used to enter the monitor](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_appleapple_10059029/page/n83) (`IRQ` at `$FA86`), but he explicitly suggests in the _BYTE_ article, "You may wish to handle the break instruction as a SWEET16 call, saving two bytes of code each time you transfer into SWEET16 mode."

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Well, having BRK dump into monitor is exactly what it's meant for. When debugging with the monitor, one writes 00 into wherever a stop is needed, hits go and ends up in monitor again when the stop is reached. Now, having BRK to enter some routine (like Sweet16) may save a byte on each call, but wastes a lot of cycles to handle address fetch and return. So it's always up to what specific optimization goal is higher prioritized. In general I'd go for cycles, as memory isn't that limited.

Comment: "In fact, being a debugging tool, readjusting the PC to the original instruction address and replacing the instruction overwritten (*1) had to be done anyway.” I suspect this is the main reason. You want to be able to add and remove breakpoints on the fly.

Answer (score 15):

The SOS operating system written for the Apple /// used `BRK` for operating system calls.  The byte following the `BRK` holds the OS function number.

Of course, the two bytes after that are also used as inline data, so you can argue that it's not a true example of `BRK` with a signature byte.  Still, it's an example of "real world" code using inline data after a `BRK`.

Regarding the `RTI`: looking at [this disassembly](http://www.apple3.org/Documents/SourceCode/Apple3_SOS_1.3.pdf), page 112 in the PDF, `IRQ.RCVR` appears to be the `BRK` entry point.  It eventually jumps to `DISPATCH` on page 118.  At the bottom of page 119 it invokes an `RTI` instruction.

---

The relevant sections of that disassembly are in the `SCMGR` system call manager at address `F0F6`. This is where control eventually passes to when a system call is invoked, after much testing and ensuring it's an *actual* system call rather some other interrupt that needs to go and handle devices.

In that code, you can see that it retrieves the invoker's return `PC` from their own stack, backs it up by one to point at the system call number (the byte immediately following the `BRK`), then stores that for system call manager use later on.

It then adjusts the invoker's return address to skip over the parameter block address, the two bytes following the system call number. That's because a system call consists of:

| Offset from BRK | Size in bytes | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | The `BRK` opcode. |
| 1 | 1 | The system call number. |
| 2 | 2 | The address of the system call parameter block. |

That will ensure an eventual `RTI` returns to the correct location after the parameter block address.

The system call manager, having saved the address of the byte immediately after the `BRK`, then uses the three bytes at that address to call the correct system call, with the specified parameters.

Comment: Good point. Haven't thought of SOS.

Comment: Fadden, added more detail on the disassembly to address how it's used, hope you don't mind. I don't think the fact that there's an *extra* two bytes used after the `brk` make this answer any less apropos.